# HTML Table not full width td

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can not get the **td with 100%** inside the table and **align the text as center**.

How can I make the `<td class="order-details">` full width, so it full the 600px of the table obove?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/61s1cdyo/1/

CODE:

```
<table class="table-bestelling-content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#ffffff">
  <tr class="details">
      <td align="center">
      <table  class="table-bestelling-content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#ffffff; max-width: 600px; display: block;">
        <tr align="center" class="header">
              <td class="order-details">
                    <h1 style="text-align: left; display: table-cell; padding: 10px 0px;">ORDER DETAILS</h1>
                </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your table is set to `display: block` so it's not longer acting as a table.

Comment: remove max-width: 600px;  And it will work fine

Comment: There is code on the JS Fiddle that isn't in your question. Put a [mcve] **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to keep the max-width: 600px, you need to remove the display: block from the inner table to make it act like a table.

```
<table class="table-bestelling-content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#ffffff">
  <tr class="details">
      <td align="center">
      <table  class="table-bestelling-content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#ffffff; max-width: 600px;">
        <tr align="center" class="header">
              <td class="order-details">
                    <h1 style="text-align: left; display: table-cell; padding: 10px 0px;">ORDER DETAILS</h1>
                </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32sdq6se/1/)

Comment: That won't help as long as the `max-width: 600px` is in there - see my answer below. (In the snippet window it just works because that's less than 600px wide, but on a full screen it won't)

Comment: His questions says he wants the TD to be the full 100% width of the 600px wide container, so I'm assuming not only is the max-width: 600px there intentionally, but it's also the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `max-width: 600px` inline setting for the nested table. If you erase that, it's 100% wide:

https://jsfiddle.net/b594a5d5/1/